# Where is "," needed?

Tags: powerbi, dax

That's my DAX code CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=1,"00",IF(LEN(LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=2,"0","")),LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3),".",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3)))=1,"00",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3)))=2,"0",""),MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3),".",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3)))=1,"00",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3)))=2,"0",""),MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3),".",IF(LEN(RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3)))=1,"00",IF(LEN(RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3)))=2,"0",""),RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3)

But it's not working, returning this error:

The syntax for ',' is incorrect. (DAX(CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=1,"00",IF(LEN(LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=2,"0","")),LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3),".",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3)))=1,"00",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3)))=2,"0",""),MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3),".",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3)))=1,"00",IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3)))=2,"0",""),MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3),".",IF(LEN(RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3)))=1,"00",IF(LEN(RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3)))=2,"0",""),RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))).

I need to format a column in a IP format like 192.168.5.2

Answer (score 1):

The DAX code you provided has several syntax errors. Here's a corrected version:

```
CONCATENATE(
    IF(LEN(LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=1, "00", IF(LEN(LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=2, "0", "")),
    LEFT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3),
    ".",
    IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3))=1, "00", IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3))=2, "0", "")),
    MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],5,3),
    ".",
    IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3))=1, "00", IF(LEN(MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3))=2, "0", "")),
    MID([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],9,3),
    ".",
    IF(LEN(RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=1, "00", IF(LEN(RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3))=2, "0", "")),
    RIGHT([PRIVATE IP ADDRESS],3)
)
```

Comment: The IP returned is that 100.244.051.151, but should return like this one 100.124.4.151
any idea?